# PyUSB on macOS: Access denied (insufficient permissions)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, libusb, macos-catalina

I tried running code as root, this is not helped.
I need raw access to usb device, *not HID*!

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hiqos.py", line 20, in <module>
    alternate_setting = usb.control.get_interface(device,interface_number) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/control.py", line 244, in get_interface
    data_or_wLength = 1)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1034, in ctrl_transfer
    self._ctx.managed_claim_interface(self, interface_number)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 167, in managed_claim_interface
    self.backend.claim_interface(self.handle, i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 811, in claim_interface
    _check(self.lib.libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle.handle, intf))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I've also tried

```
      sudo kextload -bundle-id com.apple.driver.AppleUSBFTDI
```

but my MacBook can't find it, although it was supposed to work for High Sierra. The only real thing I've been able to do is read input from /dev/disk3 after unmounting it by:

```
      sudo diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk3
```

and then

```
      sudo cat /dev/disk3 | hexdump
```